# Permission Denied problem!

Tags: permissions, terminal, kali-linux

When I try the copy or move command, it shows this:

```
cp: failed to access /root/Desktop/ : Permission denied
```

How can I solve this?
I'm using installed kali Linux in VM(windows).

Comment: You are probably logged-in as non-root user. Try switching to root, or use sudo.

Comment: Please read: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/22222

Answer (score 1):

You are clearly trying, as an unprivileged user, to copy a file in directory `/root/Desktop/` where only the root user has write access. Either switch to the root user, or use `sudo` before the `cp` command.